# Error when building boost 1.61 iostreams - recompile with -fPIC

Tags: c++, boost, centos7

I am trying to build `iostreams` boost library. I downloaded bzip2 library from here: http://www.bzip.org/downloads.html

I built it and installed using `make install`. When I try to build boost using `./b2 install` I get this error:

```
...patience...
...found 25987 targets...
...updating 3 targets...
gcc.link.dll bin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-4.8.5/release/threading-multi/libboost_iostreams.so.1.61.0
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libbz2.a(bzlib.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `BZ2_crc32Table' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libbz2.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Honestly I never ever had good experience installing boost. Average time it takes to get it to run is 6 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Just as warning suggest you should recompile `bzip2` with `-fPIC` option. You only need to add it into `CFLAGS` list in `Makefile`, like it is done in `Makefile-libbz2_so`.